# AWS Lambda use case: Processing CSV, comparing values to records in database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs

I have a particular requirement for processing a CSV of rows, each containing a database row id and other basic information (prices, stock amount, etc).

Currently, the file is being uploaded via my Restful api, then processing happens on an EC2 instances that's connected to the DB. It loops through each row, checks to see if there's a matching row id in the DB, if so, it updates the values of the existing row, otherwise, it creates a new row in the database.

Also, if there are any errors in the CSV (validation issues, etc) then I don't  process any of the rows and exit from the process entirely (with error messages).

The question is, if I convert this to a Lambda function, I would need the DB id checking code in the Lambda also? I believe it would slow things down in the Lambda if it had to process a large CSV.

One approach would be to have one function to initially check the CSV for any errors and split the CSV into rows parts, then to have those onto a queue (SQS?), the have separate Lambdas to watch the queue and process to add / update each in the database. Does this sound like a reasonable solution?

Comment: How many rows might be in a file? How long does it typically take to process this file (on what Instance Type)? The only real limitations in Lambda are the 15-minute execution time and 500MB of temporary disk space. If you can fit within those limits, then a Lambda function sounds fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recommended approach to validate the CSV and then send each update task to an SQS queue sounds perfectly reasonable. I recommend going with that approach.